# How I change a value of hidden file in the file HTML.Twig

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig

I have in a file `HTML.twig`:

1: a `one` hidden filed should take 3 values according which radio selected, one from my database and the two others value are 10.

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt_filed" value="{{ price.getLt }}" or "10" or "10">
```

2: The 3 radio Box

```
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" onchange='valueLt();' value="Spare {{ price.getSparePrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="rep-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" onchange='valueLt();' value="Repair{{ price.getRepairPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="tes-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" onchange='valueLt();' value="Test {{ price.getTestPrice }}" type="radio">
```

3: I did a block Javascript in the same file HTML.Twig, I created a function to get the values of each radio, this following:

```
{% block javasc %}
<script>
        function valueLt(){
          var spare= document.getElementById('spa-price');
          var repair= document.getElementById('rep-price');
          var test= document.getElementById('tes-price');

          var hidden_filed =   document.getElementsByName("lt_filed");


          if (repair.checked){ // Should take the value 10
              alert("repair checked");
              hidden_filed.value = 10;

          } else if (test.checked){ // Should take the value 10 also
             alert("test checked");
             hidden_filed.value = 10;

          } else {
             alert("spare checked"); // should take the value from my database
             hidden_filed.value = {{ price.getLt }};// Here I can't recovred   the value from the Database

            }
        }
     </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Can you tell me how I can get the value `{{ price.getLt }}` by Twig or javascript ?

Thank you.

Comment: @Brad Larson What's your problem you are developper in Android and I asked a question in javascript and PHP so for the next time you should answer just the question in your domain okkk

Comment: Uh, this is a word-for-word duplicate of your other question. I don't need to know anything about the domain to tell you that these are duplicates. Please don't repeat questions.

Comment: How I will repeat it and my acount is closed!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, `document.getElementsByName(param)` function doesn't return an element instance, it returns an array of elements. You should pick first element like that :

```
{% block javasc %}
<script>
        function valueLt(){
          var spare= document.getElementById('spa-price');
          var repair= document.getElementById('rep-price');
          var test= document.getElementById('tes-price');

          var hidden_filed =   document.getElementsByName("lt_filed")[0]; // CHANGE THIS LINE

          if (repair.checked){ // Should take the value 10
              alert("repair checked");
              hidden_filed.value = 10;

          } else if (test.checked){ // Should take the value 10 also
             alert("test checked");
             hidden_filed.value = 10;

          } else {
             alert("spare checked"); // should take the value from my database
             hidden_filed.value = {{ price.getLt }};// Here I can't recovred   the value from the Database

            }
        }
     </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it concern the last condition, how I can get the value in the hidden file according the one in the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden file" sir ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was typing error, I mean hidden field (HTML).